# 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus' not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.0, and I'm using Twitter Bootstrap [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com). I am trying to use the 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus', but when I put in the class, it doesn't show.

[image]

P.S. I am using the page http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css to link to bootstrap

Code:

I only have one icon and no styling for it.

```
<button id='b'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>
```

Comment: Provide some sample code. Without any context, its hard to troubleshoot. Separately, you could be improperly linking the image for the glyph icons.

Answer (score 6):

I have attached a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55qJC/) showing the code and CSS link you supplied.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
    <button id='b'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
    </button>
</body>
```

The plus button is shown as expected

Comment: There was an edit just a few minutes ago to add that line of code - it wasn't there a day ago, when first posted

Comment: you must also have something else in you site (other than just this button) that is causing the issue you are having. The code shown produces a grey button with a plus in it. Either show the code (HTML and CSS for the elements down to and including the button) if you want someone to help. Or check the code in your site yourself to see if there is another style that is interfering with the display of the button. What styles does you button have from your own CSS, We can only assume its in a list or nested div or something else from the image in your post?

Answer (score 0):

It was an extremely simple mistake. I forgot to add the `rel='stylesheet'` and `type='text/css'`.

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad we could help you get to a right answer.